# Filter json children without data

Tags: json, kubectl, jsonpath

Is it possibile to extract all the childrens of a parent node without respective data?
For example, using jsonpath, I'd want list all options available under "spec", like below

```
containers 
restartPolicy 
dnsPolicy
```

```
{
    "kind": "Pod",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "nginx",
        "creationTimestamp": null,
        "labels": {
            "run": "nginx"
        }
    },
    "spec": {
        "containers": [
            {
                "name": "nginx",
                "image": "nginx",
                "resources": {}
            }
        ],
        "restartPolicy": "Always",
        "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst"
    },
    "status": {}
}
```

Comment: Have a look at what JSONPath can do

Comment: Using what language? None are tagged here. JSON itself is a string data format and not programmable itself

Comment: Using jsonpath so I can pass it from kubectl

Answer (score 0):

you could use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) for parsing JSON output of kubectl commands. The below command will give keys of that level as you want.

```
kubectl get po ... -o json | jq '.spec | keys '
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Why the result is different if I search inside spec.containers? Like `kubectl run pod --image=nginx --dry-run=client -o json | jq '.spec.containers | keys '`